Linking the Fourier transform and the Fourier series inversion theorem
I have a question regarding the relationship between the Fourier transform and the Fourier series inversion theorem, particularly in the context of approximate identities.
Here is a very intuitive sketch of the proof of the Fourier transform inversion theorem. Consider a rapidly decreasing function $ f(x) $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ such that $ f(0) = 1 $ (we often choose $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ but other functions work as well). Let $ \hat{f}$ be the Fourier transform of $f $, and define$f_c(x) = f(cx) $. When $ c $ tends to $0$, $ f_c(x)$ tends to $1$. Using the following property of the Fourier transform:
$$
   \hat{f_c}(x) = \frac{1}{|c|} \hat{f}\left(\frac{x}{c}\right),
$$
it's relatively straightforward to prove that, up to a constant $C=\int \hat f$, $ \hat{f_c}$ is an approximate identity. Consequently, one can prove that if $\hat{g}$ is integrable, then $ \int \hat{g} = Cg(0) $ using the equality $ \langle \hat{g}, f_c \rangle = \langle g, \hat{f_c} \rangle $.
The proof the Fourier series inversion theorem using Fejér kernels is somewhat similar to the Fourier transform case. Consider the sequence $ c_n(k) $ defined as:
$$
c_n(k) = \begin{cases} 
1 - \frac{|k|}{n} & \text{for } |k| < n \\
0 & \text{for } |k| \geq n
\end{cases}
$$
The Fejér kernel $\hat{c_n}(x)$ is then the Fourier series defined by these coefficients $c_n(k)$. When $ n $ tends to $\infty$, $ c_n(k)$ tends to $1$. It can be shown from direct computation that $\hat{c}_n(x)$ is an approximate identity on $T$ (the circle). When $\hat g$ is summable, by using the equality $\langle \hat{g}, c_n \rangle = \langle g, \hat{c_n} \rangle$, it is straightforward to prove that $\sum \hat g(k) = g(0)$.
However, proving that $ \hat{c}_n(x) $ is an approximate identity seems far less intuitive compared to proving that $ \hat{f_c}(x) $ is an approximate identity, and it seems necessary to explicitly compute the expression for $ \hat{c}_n(x) $. I'm wondering if there's a more general method to verify that $ \hat{c_n}(x)$ is an approximate identity.
Question:
I have a conjecture: if $ f(x) $ is a rapidly decreasing function on $ \mathbb{R}$ with $ f(0) = 1 $ and if $ c_n(k) = f(k/n)$, then $ \hat{c_n}(x) $ is an approximate identity on $ T $. This conjecture could potentially link the Fourier transform and the Fourier series inversion theorem more effectively. I'm not sure whether this conjecture is correct or how to prove it.
For example, when $ f(x) = \max(0, 1 - |x|) $, which, although not rapidly decreasing, yields $ \hat{c_n}(x) $ as the Fejér kernel. When $f(x)$ is the indicator function on $[-1,1]$, $ \hat{c_n}(x) $ is the Dirichlet kernel, which is not an approximate identity. This suggests that the regularity of $ f(x)$ might be crucial.
Is my conjecture correct, and how could one approach proving it?

Your notation is a little confusing to me. By $$\hat{f}_c(x)=\frac{1}{|c|}, \hat{f}\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$$ do you mean $$\hat{f}_c(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_xf_c(x)=\frac{1}{|c|}, \mathcal{F}_x[f(x)]\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)=\frac{1}{|c| }, F\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)?$$

Also, I believe the Fourier inversion theorem is equivalent to the convergence of the "nested" Fourier series representation

$$f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}{\omega}F(\omega)=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega), e^{2 \pi i x \omega} , d\omega\=\lim\limits_{N, f\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=-2 f (2 n-1)}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right), F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=-4 f (2 n-1)}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k, F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, the evaluation frequency $f$ in the inner sum over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer, and
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}xf(x)=\int\limits{-\infty}^\infty f(x), e^{-2 \pi i \omega x}, dx\tag{2}$$
is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. (see my related question on MathOverflow)
